# What's an importance of multi-valued functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivalued-functions

For example, let's define $\log z= \{w\in \mathbb{C} : e^w=z\}$. Then, we call this set $\log z$ a "multi-valued function".

Formally saying, this $\log z$ is merely a set but not a function to $\mathbb{C}$ and i think this notation makes confusion. Why is this concept important in complex analysis? What is disadvantage of considering **only** principal function of those multivalued function?

Comment: Often one does only consider the principal branch. Other times one wants to find *all* solutions to an equation involving exponentials. We may also want to study Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

For my complex analysis course this information was important when we trying to determine the domain of the function as well as integrating over various contours using residues. This process was also used as you pointed out to make the complex $\log$ an actual function of a complex variable.

Comment: Is it possible to define complex function f (on whole plane) which is continuous .and if f(z)=t then $t \times t=z$ ?